# Docker-Compose from local to AWS EC2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, axios

I am new in Web development, and now I got some obstacles bothering me a couple of days. I successfully built my web app by docker-compose locally.

Then I tried to use docker-compose to run my both front and backend on EC2 Linux instance.

However, although now the frontend was showing publicly, but now unable to GET the data from my backend. Got an error message: " net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". Looks like my the connection between front and back is broken.

I am wondering since the docker-compose.yaml is running successfully on local. It should also be working on the EC2 instance?

Any suggestion would be helpful. Thank you.

**Docker-Compose.yaml:**

```
Version: "3.2"
services:
  project:
    restart: always
    container_name: coin
    command : bash -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    build:
      context: ./coin_api/
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  frontend:
    restart: always
    command : npm start
    container_name: front
    build:
      context: ./frontend/
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000" 
    stdin_open: true
networks:
  db-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Security Group of the EC2 Instance:

[image]

Comment: Client-side code runs in your browser. What address is it trying to make requests to?

Comment: I connected to my EC2 instance public IP address, and trying to make requests through my current browser to my backend 127.0.0.1:8000.